# How to pass parameter to HTTP Get method from .Net Core + React

Tags: reactjs, api, asp.net-core, parameters, axios

We have created a .Net core Web API project with React & redux template. Now we wanted to call an Http Get method which contains a parameter. I am new to react and API concepts so how to do it? I have tried like following, it's not working properly or it shows always 401 or 415 error. Where I did go wrong?

React with Axios,

```
var getaproveUserDetails = axios.
    get("/users/getapprove", {
        params: { email: EmailOfUser }
    }

    ).then(function (response) {
        var res = response.json();
        console.log("response", 'res: ' + res.message, response.message);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    });
```

My API method,

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("getapprove/{email}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetApprove([FromQuery]string Email)
    {
           if (Email == null)
                return BadRequest("Email is Null!.");

            var user = _userService.GetByEmail(Email);
            if (user == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(user);
     }
```

My Controller Route,

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UsersController {...    ...
```

Comment: When are you getting a 401 and when are you getting a 415 HTTP status code back? You are providing the parameter to the request in the wrong way. You should make the get request this way: `axios.get("/users/getapprove/${EmailOfUser}").then()..` and remove the `[FromQuery]` attribute. A 2nd way is to keep your code and remove the `/{email}` part from the `[HttpGet]` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have changed the request route by   `[HttpGet("getapprove/{email}")]`, so, you need to call this api action by this route : `"/users/getapprove/"+ EmailOfUser` instead of params.

> If you pass params, the get url will become
>   `/users/getapprove?email=EmailOfUser` which is inconsistent with the
>   route rule you set.

You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#http-verb-templates).

Also, the receive parameter in GetApprove named `Email` ,the name of the routing parameter you set is `email`.

As you added `[FromQuery]` , so you need to make sure their names are exactly the same. Or delete the `[FromQuery]` attribute which allows different capitalization.

To solve this issue, change your code like this:

```
var getaproveUserDetails = axios.
    get("/users/getapprove/" + EmailOfUser  
    ).then(function (response) {
        var res = response.json();
        console.log("response", 'res: ' + res.message, response.message);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    });
```

Api (One way) :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("getapprove/{Email}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetApprove([FromQuery]string Email)
{
       if (Email == null)
            return BadRequest("Email is Null!.");

        var user = _userService.GetByEmail(Email);
        if (user == null)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(user);
 }
```

Api (another way):

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("getapprove/{email}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetApprove(string Email)
    {
           if (Email == null)
                return BadRequest("Email is Null!.");

            var user = _userService.GetByEmail(Email);
            if (user == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(user);
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Yu :)

Answer (score -1):

1. Error 401 means Unauthorize.

And [Authorize] in asp.net core web API means that route is secured, pass your auth code in axios header, if you are using JWT token, it's going to look like

`Authentication: "Bearer {token}"`

where the variable token is your token.

2. Your controller class is suppose to inherit from ControllerBase, like

`public class UserController : ControllerBase`